# Is there a repdigit that is powerful number(Achilles numbers)?

Tags: number-theory, repunit-numbers

Is there a repdigit that is powerful number(Achilles numbers)?

Powerful numbers(Achilles Numbers) are the numbers whose exponents in prime factors is greater than $1$, but not possible to write it as a perfect power.(Ex. $3528$)

We know that repdigit is never a perfect power as said [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064016/how-sure-can-we-be-that-underbrace-k-cdots-k-m-ks-cannot-be-a-perfect), but how about being a powerful number?

There are some cases which $\underbrace{n\cdots nn}_{x\text{ times}}$ cannot be a powerful number, such when $n=2, 5, 6$.

In some cases, it is dependent, for example, if $n=3$, then it can be only powerful if $x\equiv1\pmod{3}$, or if $n=7$, then $x\equiv0\pmod{6}$ in order to be powerful number.

I used Paridroid to check if are there any repdigit that is powerful number, but I didn’t find one.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is actually known that a repdigit cannot be a perfect power , but at least this is almost surely impossible. That such a number is poweful is very unlikely as well since I would expect that every repunit has a prime factor larger than $10$ with exponent $1$ in the prime factorization. This would imply the conjecture that a repdigit cannot be powerful (except with $1$ digit)